# Div Positioning is calculated fine but need explanation how it is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone explain how this is working.  I am creating sidepanel ad and to place the panels i want the position of the width. When i upload the script on my server then i get a small script which we place on the publisher website and where our script runs inside the iframe. Here is the screen shot.

[image: Screenshot]

My script is highlighted in yellow which is getting the position of the div which is in red box class='content'.

Here is the code i have used.

```
function getPosition(element) {
            var xPosition = 0;
            var yPosition = 0;
            var left = 0;
            var top = 0;
            var i = 0;
            while (element) {
                xPosition = (element.offsetLeft);
                yPosition = (element.offsetTop);
                console.log("TOP Pos: "+yPosition+"Left Pos: "+xPosition);
                if (i == 1) {
                    left = xPosition;
                    top = yPosition;
               }
                element = element.offsetParent;
                i++;
            }
            return {
                x: left,
                y: top
            };
        }
```

This is how i am calling the getPosition method

```
 function ReadDivPos(selector) {
            var _divPos = "";
            var parentDoc = window;
            while (parentDoc !== parentDoc.parent) {
                parentDoc = parentDoc.parent;
            }
            parentDoc = parentDoc.document;
            var parentDiv = parentDoc.getElementsByTagName('div');
            var divs = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < parentDiv.length; i++) {
                if (parentDiv[i].className == "content") {
                    var pos = getPosition(parentDiv[i]);
                    var x = pos["x"];
                    var y = pos["y"];
                    console.log("Values+ Top: " + y + " Left: " + x);
                    var w = parentDiv[i].offsetWidth;
                    _divPos += x + "," + w + "," + y + "," + (x + w) + ","+window.screen.availWidth+"\\n";
                }
            }
            console.log("Values+ x: " + _divPos);
            return _divPos;
        }
```

This is the values i am getting .

[image: Screenshot]

I got the correct values in the second attempt ,i.e,

```
 TOP Pos: 185Left Pos: 197
```

Top:185 and Left 197 which is correct but why i got Top 2 and Left 0 for the first time and second time i got correct values. Since i am getting the values in the second attempt so i have fixed this using i==1

```
if (i == 1) {
     left = xPosition;
     top = yPosition;
 }
```

i dont think this is the best approach but thats how i am getting the correct values. can anyone explain me this why it is working fine on the second attempt. Thanks in advance

Anyone explain me this ? Thanks

Comment: can anyone explain me this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that it's because the element you're searching for (by the way, getElementsByClassName is a thing) is relatively positioned to the element containing it and thus has position 0,2 or what-ev.

That getPosition function crawls up the parent tree, so the parent node spits out the right position because it's relative to the document.

Finally, the document itself is relative to itself and thus has zero offset.

Comment: Thanks for the reply what do you mean by getElementsByClassName

Comment: You're finding all div elements (which I think you think is actually only finding the root div elements?) and then iterating through them looking for a class.  getElementsByClassName() is a na tive function that does the same thing more performantly.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: how can i use getElementsByClassName in my code if it is more better way of what i am doing now then i would use that

Comment: i have used this i think but i was not able to find the div so i have found this code to get the parentDiv and then getting the position

Comment: Accept my answer, setup a plnkr.co with your code, and I'll show you.  Otherwise, check out the examples in the link I posted.

Comment: I did explain why the first item and last item are not offset and the inner item is the right offset.  You are finding the right content element but it's the parent of that item who's offset is useful to you since the parent of the content element is relative to the document

Comment: i have accepted your answer can you show me how can edit my code to make it more efficient