# Div positioning calculation explanation required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have attached the screenshot below to explain what i am trying to do.

[image: Screenshot]

The yellow highlighted line is the script which is run to get the position of the div (The red box in the picture).

I have used this code to calculate the position.

```
function getPosition(element) {
            var xPosition = 0;
            var yPosition = 0;
            var left = 0;
            var top = 0;
            var i = 0;
            while (element) {
                xPosition = (element.offsetLeft);
                yPosition = (element.offsetTop);
                console.log("TOP Pos: "+yPosition+"Left Pos: "+xPosition);
                if (i == 1) {
                    left = xPosition;
                    top = yPosition;
               }
                element = element.offsetParent;
                i++;
            }
            return {
                x: left,
                y: top
            };
        }
```

And here i have used this method

```
function ReadDivPos(selector) {
            var _divPos = "";
            var parentDoc = window;
            while (parentDoc !== parentDoc.parent) {
                parentDoc = parentDoc.parent;
            }
            parentDoc = parentDoc.document;
            var parentDiv = parentDoc.getElementsByTagName('div');
            var divs = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < parentDiv.length; i++) {
                if (parentDiv[i].className == "content") {
                    var pos = getPosition(parentDiv[i]);
                    var x = pos["x"];
                    var y = pos["y"];
                    console.log("Values+ Top: " + y + " Left: " + x);
                    var w = parentDiv[i].offsetWidth;
                    _divPos += x + "," + w + "," + y + "," + (x + w) + ","+window.screen.availWidth+"\\n";
                }
            }
            console.log("Values+ x: " + _divPos);
            return _divPos;
        }
```

Interestingly i am getting three values and on the second attempt i am getting the correct values. Here is the screenshot showing all the three values.

[image: Screenshot 2]

The correct value is

```
 TOP Pos: 185Left Pos: 197
```

which i got it in the second attempt. Can anyone explain me why i did not get the correct values in the first attempt or is there any efficient way to get these values. I have to get the parent node because this was the only way to access the div class='content' as script is placed before the div content so i have to read the parent nodes and then i am able to access the required div.

Please Note this is the copy of my original question([Div Positioning is calculated fine but need explanation how it is working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790897/div-positioning-is-calculated-fine-but-need-explanation-how-it-is-working)). The guy asked me to accept his answer and then he will show how it is done but he never came back to me once i accepted his answer and unfortunately i have also forgot my userid so i am able to logon to my orignal account.

If someone just explain me why this is giving me correct positions in the second attempt. I am new to frontend development if i understand this concept then it will help in my future projects. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include a minimal working example of the problem, with DOM, in your question.

Comment: this is really a job for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)... `$('.container--page.content').offset().left;`

Comment: @Nit sorry what do you mean by working example of the problem? I am using two methods and included them in the question and these are used to get the div positions

Comment: You haven't included the HTML you're working with.

Comment: @Nit well basically i am working in an ad agency and this is a sidepanel ads. What we usually do is upload our script on the server which gives us the small script which we place inside publisher website where our script runs in an iframe and call our script. If you look at the first screenshot there is an iframe where my script (highlighted yellow) is called and reading the div content (highlighted red) .

Comment: @shennan i have tried this but not working